# How to determine the parent object of a property

Tags: javascript

I have an object `obj` and we can apply to property `prop` via `obj` (i.e. value by the `obj.prop` reference is not `undefined`).

How can I detect the object in a prototype chain to which the property belongs?

Comment: hasOwnProperty() and instanceOf() are the droids you're looking for

Comment: `obj.hasOwnProperty()` + `obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` ... repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible soluiion using non-standard `__proto__`:

```
function printProtoForProp(obj, propName) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
        console.log(obj);
    } else if (obj.__proto__ != null) {
        printProtoForProp(obj.__proto__, propName);
    }
}
```

---

Edit: you could replace `obj.__proto__` with `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` (as per @Felix Kling comment under OP).

Comment: Since it is non-standard you *should* replace it…